# Number of connections per host in Datastax C++ driver

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0

I've not been able to understand the role of a 'connection' in the execution of a query on a host.

[cass_cluster_set_core_connections_per_host](https://datastax.github.io/cpp-driver/api/struct.CassCluster/) sets the number of connections made to each server in each IO thread. Why is this parameter configurable? What's the benefit of having more than 1 connection per IO thread? What decides the optimum value for this parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function sets the initial number of connections per host, and it could be increased up to value set by `cass_cluster_set_max_connections_per_host` function (by default it's 2). New connection is created when the number of in-flight request is greater than set by `cass_cluster_set_max_concurrent_requests_threshold` (default 100).  You can set higher value with `cass_cluster_set_core_connections_per_host` if you know that you'll generate the big number of in-flight request from the beginning - in this case you won't spend time opening an additional connection when you're executing requests.

Comment: I've still not been able to visualize a connection. What exactly is a connection? I understand what a thread is, but why will a thread need multiple connections to execute a given number of requests? How come one is not enought?

Comment: On Cassandra side the resources also required to handle all these requests, and sometimes it could makes sense to have multiple connection to spread the load between threads on Cassandra side. I believe that documentation for Java driver explains this better: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.5/manual/pooling/

Comment: Currently my high level view is like this; if we have got 'x' number of IO threads, then those threads can asynchronously execute queries on the Cluster nodes. If we consider a single thread out of those x threads, that single thread will be able to synchronously pass on queries to the cluster nodes via a connection. I guess there's something wrong in this view because if it's right I don't know how having multiple connections per IO thread improve anything?

Comment: The reason multiple connections came to be for the drivers was due to the number of streams (stream ids) that were available per connection (v2 allowed for 128 where as v3+ allows for 32,768).

Comment: As @Fero already pointed out - there are different limitations on number of in-flight requests per connection. Also, regarding your comment about X IO threads - this is a different scalability model - you may have a case when one thread may handle all load, but you need to split requests between multiple connections. If you have multiple IO threads, then yes - multiple connections per thread may not be required

Comment: I feel like there's some fundamental/basic concept here which I've still not been able to understand. I am still not able to relate 'cass_cluster_set_core_connections_per_host' with 'cass_cluster_set_num_threads_io'. I just don't see how multiple threads and then on top of that, multiple connections can achieve something(execution of queries) which multiple threads and a single connection can not. In the datastax link, it's mentioned that, "the driver writes a request containing the stream id and the query on the connection". Now if I've configured x IO threads(cass_cluster_set_num_threads_io)

Comment: If you're using multiple threads, then using 1 connections is ok - you're scalling throughput via threads. But the same could be achieved by using fewer threads and more connections per thread - this is depends on architecture of your application, type of data processing in callbacks, etc.